# Is it possible to change two function using parfor loop?

Tags: matlab, function, parfor

Suppose I have two functions written on different scripts, say `function1.m` and `function2.m` The two computation in the two functions are independent (Some inputs may be the same, say `function1(x,y)` and `function2(x,z)` for example). However, running sequentially, say `ret1 = function1(x,y); ret2 = function2(x,z);` may be time consuming. I wonder if it is possible to run it in `parfor` loop:

```
parfor i = 1:2
ret(i) = run(['function' num2str(i)]); % if i=1,ret(1)=function1 and i=2, ret(2)=function2
end
```

Is it possible to write it in `parfor` loop?

Answer (score 3):

Your idea is correct, but the implementation is wrong.

Matlab won't let you use `run` within `parfor` as it can't make sure it's a valid way to use `parfor` (i.e. no dependencies between iterations). The proper way to do that is to use functions (and not scrips) and an `if` statement to choose between them:

```
ret = zeros(2,1);
parfor k = 1:2
    if k==1, ret(k) = f1(x,y);  end
    if k==2, ret(k) = f2(x,z);  end
end
```

here `f1` and `f2` are some functions that return a scalar value (so it's suitable for `ret(k)` and each instance of the loop call a different `if` statement.

You can read here more about [how to convert scripts to functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/scripts-and-functions.html).

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb for a `parfor` loop is that each iteration must be standalone. More accurately,

> [The body of the parfor-loop must be independent. One loop iteration
>   cannot depend on a previous iteration, because the iterations are
>   executed in a nondeterministic order.](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfor.html)

That means that every iteration must be one which can be performed on its own and produce the correct result.

Therefore, if you have code that says, for instance,

```
parfor (i = 1:2)
    function1(iterator,someNumber); 
    function2(iterator,someNumber);
end
```

there should be no issue with applying parfor.

However, if you have code that says, for instance,

```
persistentValue = 0;
parfor (i = 1:2)
    persistentValue = persistentValue + function1(iterator,someNumber); 
    function2(iterator,persistentValue);
end
```

it would not be usable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  It is possible.

Here's an example:

```
ret = zeros(2,1);
fHandles = {@min, @max};
x = 1:10;        
parfor i=1:2
    ret(i) = fHandles{i}(x);    
end
ret   % show the results.
```

Whether this is a good idea or not, I don't know.  There is overhead to setting up the parallel processing that may or may not make it worthwhile for you.

1. Typically the more iterations you have computed, the more value you get from setting up a `parfor` loop as the iterations are sliced-up and sent non-deterministically to the separate cores for processing.  So you're getting use of 2 cores right now, but if you have many functions this may improve things.
2. The order that the iterations are run is not guaranteed (it could be that one core gets assigned a range of values for i, but we do not know if it those values are taken in order or randomly), so your code can't depend on other iterations of the loop.

In general, the MATLAB editor is pretty at flagging these issues ahead of time.

**EDIT**

Here's a proof of concept for a variable number of arguments to your different functions

```
ret = zeros(2,1);
fHandles = {@min, @max};
x = 1:10;         % x is a 1x10 vector
y = rand(20);     % y is a 20x20 matrix
z = 1;            % z is a scalar value
fArgs = {{x};
         {y,z}};  %wrap your arguments up in a cell
parfor i=1:2
    ret(i) = fHandles{i}([fArgs{i}{:}]);  %calls the function with its variable sized arguments here
end
ret   % show the output
```

Again, this is just proof-of-concept.  There are big warnings showing up in MATLAB about having to *broadcast* `fArgs` across all of the cores.

Comment: Thanks. How about if the input for the two functions are not the same? say function1 require x and y while function2 require x and z (y and z can be different).

Comment: Are these variables being determined within the parfor loop or can they be outside of it?  Is the bigger issue or question, how to handle variable size inputs for varying functions?

Comment: See my edit for an example on how to handle multiple arguments.

Comment: The variables can be determined outside. Also, the variable size can be different for different input (at least y and z may have different sizes)

Comment: Did my updated example make sense then?  The variables `x`, `y`, and `z` are all of different sizes and the number of inputs to the functions is different for each case.  Let me know if that's not what you are mean.  I'm not sure if you are asking for something different or it is not clear from my code that the variables are different sizes.

Comment: I just updated the comments in my example code to show the variable size for `x`, `y`, and `z`.  In the parfor example, `x` (a 1x10 vector) is passed to function(1) , `min`, while `y` (a 20x20 matrix) and `z` (a scalar) are passed as arguments to function(2), `max`.  Good luck.

Comment: Yes, I just add to make it clear after seeing your comments to make my question clear. No need to be panic. I should add a statement that I saw your updated solution.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  Does this answer your question then?  Do you want to accept it as a solution?